# Meteorjs collection find with $where

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a meteorjs application with a collection with a `ticker` field.
I need the `$where` statement because I want to compare two fields in the same collection:

```
Tickers.find({$where: function() { return (this.price < this.value); }})
```

It didn't worked and I did a simpler test with `$where`.
On server side, when I run this query:

```
var t = Tickers.find({ticker:'AAPL'});
```

`t` contains the right value: one item with 'AAPL' ticker value. When I use:

```
t = Tickers.find({$where: function() { return (this.ticker === 'AAPL'); }});
```

`t` contains all the items in the collection.
The same `$where` query instead on client side works, but I don't want to publish the (huge) collection to do the query on client side.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it didn't work? Are you receiving an error, or the wrong value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** function as a string, not as an actual function. This is needed for Mongo to process and run the function (it is not being done in Node.js). Follow this [forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ErgCC4g_bB0) for more on this.

Thus change your query to

```
Tickers.find({"$where": "function() { return (this.price < this.value); }"})
```

or simply pass in the string comparison

```
Tickers.find("this.price < this.value");
```

However, bear in mind that this won't perfom very well since using the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** operator calls the JavaScript engine to evaluate Javascript code on every document and checks the condition for each. It is advisable to combine with indexed queries if you can so that the query may be faster.

Some **[considerations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations)** you have to look at when using **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)**:

> Do not use global variables.
>
> **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes.
>   Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query
>   using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., **`$gt`**, **`$in`**). In general, you
>   should use **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** only when you can’t express your query using another
>   operator. If you must use **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)**, try to include at least one other
>   standard query operator to filter the result set. Using **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** alone
>   requires a table scan. Using normal non-**[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** query statements
>   provides the following performance advantages:
>
> MongoDB will evaluate non-**[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** components of query before **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)**
>   statements. If the non-**[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** statements match no documents, MongoDB
>   will not perform any query evaluation using **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)**. The non-**[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)**
>   query statements may use an index.

Another suggestion that avoids using the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where)** operator would be to create an additional computed denormalized field say `price_difference` that is the difference between price and value (value - price) which you can then query as:

```
Tickers.find({ "price_difference": { "$gt": 0 }});
```

But still, such low-selectivity fields don't yield good index performance if the collection is very large thus the candidate set for indexing is large with this approach.

Comment: Thanks cridam for the good idea: I will create the additional computed denormalized field.